# Drawing tree-like symbols

Tags: symbols

In Martin Hairer's '[Introduction to Regularity Structures](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Regularity.pdf)', on page 22, the following appears:
[image]

Any suggestions on how I might be able to draw these tree-like symbols in LaTex?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is a flexible approach to draw such trees. To change the size of the tree, change the length `\RSu`; the initial value is `\setlength\RSu{1ex}`.
You can easily define more operators by looking at the current definitions:

```
\RSdef{i}{\draw (\X) -- +(90:\RSu) node{};}
\RSdef{l}{\draw (\X) -- +(135:\RSu) node{};}
\RSdef{r}{\draw (\X) -- +(45:\RSu) node{};}
\RSdef{I}{\draw (\X) -- +(90:\RSu) coordinate(\X I);\edef\X{\X I}}
\RSdef{L}{\draw (\X) -- +(135:\RSu) coordinate(\X L);\edef\X{\X L}}
\RSdef{R}{\draw (\X) -- +(45:\RSu) coordinate(\X R);\edef\X{\X R}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\RSloop{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\RSloopa\RSloopb}
\makeatother
\newcommand\RSloopa[1]{\bgroup\RSloop#1\relax\egroup\RSloop}
\newcommand\RSloopb[1]%
  {\ifx\relax#1%
   \else
     \ifcsname RS:#1\endcsname
       \csname RS:#1\endcsname
     \else
       \GenericError{(RS)}{RS Error: operator #1 undefined}{}{}%
     \fi
   \expandafter\RSloop
   \fi
  }
\newcommand\X{0}
\newcommand\RS[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
     [every node/.style=
       {circle,draw,fill,minimum size=1.5pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
      line cap=round
     ]
   \coordinate(\X) at (0,0);
   \RSloop{#1}\relax
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\newcommand\RSdef[1]{\expandafter\def\csname RS:#1\endcsname}
\newlength\RSu
\RSu=1ex
\RSdef{i}{\draw (\X) -- +(90:\RSu) node{};}
\RSdef{l}{\draw (\X) -- +(135:\RSu) node{};}
\RSdef{r}{\draw (\X) -- +(45:\RSu) node{};}
\RSdef{I}{\draw (\X) -- +(90:\RSu) coordinate(\X I);\edef\X{\X I}}
\RSdef{L}{\draw (\X) -- +(135:\RSu) coordinate(\X L);\edef\X{\X L}}
\RSdef{R}{\draw (\X) -- +(45:\RSu) coordinate(\X R);\edef\X{\X R}}
\begin{document}

\section*{The operators}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb"l" & line left and draw node      & \RS{l} \\
\verb"i" & line up and draw node        & \RS{i} \\
\verb"r" & line right and draw node     & \RS{r} \\
\verb"L" & line left and move position  & \RS{L} \\
\verb"I" & line up and move position    & \RS{I} \\
\verb"R" & line right and move position & \RS{R} \\
\verb"{...}" & confine position change &
\end{tabular}

\section*{Examples}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \RS{lir}    & \verb"\RS{lir}"    \\
  \RS{lr}     & \verb"\RS{lr}"     \\
  \RS{lrIlir} & \verb"\RS{lrIlir}" \\
  \RS{i}      & \verb"\RS{i}"      \\
  \RS{rIlir}  & \verb"\RS{rIlir}"  \\
  \RS{lrIlr}  & \verb"\RS{lrIlr}"  \\
  \RS{Ilir}   & \verb"\RS{Ilir}"   \\
  \RS{Ilir}   & \verb"\RS{Ilir}"   \\
  \RS{rIlr}   & \verb"\RS{rIlr}"   \\
  \RS{{LL{Lil}{Ii}{Ri}}{RR{Li}{Ii}{Rir}}} &
    \verb"\RS{{LL{Lil}{Ii}{Ri}}{RR{Li}{Ii}{Rir}}}"
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. This should be a package!

Comment: @gernot I was genuinely not expecting such a good answer. Thank you for having put in the effort to write this for me (and, indeed, all of us)!

Comment: @Richard Thanks for your enthusiasm. I'm afraid that at the moment the use cases for such a package are quite limited, For more flexible trees there are already packages. So let's wait for the killer app that will justify such a package ;-)

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Well, it was a nice question also. And it was fun on a Saturday afternoon.

Comment: Really nice. One day I'll understand the loop trick.... Maybe ;-)

Comment: @Rmano The "loop trick" is not such a trick. See the post ["Looping over strings"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359189/110998). The second of the three loops is basically the one I used here. There are several explanations how these loops work, maybe one is to your liking.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there are packages for this symbol out there.

If I'm going to draw these graphical notations, I might give `tikz` a try.

EDIT(add example):

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany,landscape]{ctexbook}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\usepackage[hmargin={1cm},vmargin={5.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (t1_0) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (t1_1) at ($(t1_0) + (130:6mm)$);
\coordinate (t1_2) at ($(t1_0) + (0,6mm)$);
\coordinate (t1_3) at ($(t1_0) + (50:6mm)$);
\draw [thick] (t1_1) to (t1_0) to (t1_3);
\draw [thick] (t1_0) to (t1_2);
\filldraw (t1_1) circle [radius=1mm];
\filldraw (t1_2) circle [radius=1mm];
\filldraw (t1_3) circle [radius=1mm];

\coordinate (t2_0) at (1cm, 0);
\coordinate (t2_1) at ($(t2_0) + (70:6mm)$);
\coordinate (t2_2) at ($(t2_0) + (110:6mm)$);
\draw [thick] (t2_1) to (t2_0) to (t2_2);
\filldraw (t2_1) circle [radius=1mm];
\filldraw (t2_2) circle [radius=1mm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/120389)

Comment: Can you improve the answer by providing at least one of the symbols in TikZ?

Comment: Does the edited answer work?

Comment: @pkuphy, much better :)

Comment: @Moriambar sorry, I'll do better the next time