# Adding the header and footer for latex

Tags: header-footer

I want to add footer and header for my latex homework. And I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
```

But my article has no reaction.

The following is my code before start of the article.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\documentclass[multi=false,tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fullpage,mathpazo,amsfonts,nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackag[top=2cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,includehead,includefoot]   {geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\newcommand\ALloop[1]%
{\ifx\relax#1%
\else
 \ifcsname AL:#1\endcsname
   \csname AL:#1\endcsname
 \else
   \GenericError{(AL)}{AL Error: operator #1 undefined}{}{}%
 \fi
\expandafter\ALloop
\fi
}
\newcommand\AL[1]%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,every node/.style={blob}]
\coordinate(X) at (0,0);
\ALloop#1\relax
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\ALs{12}% small radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALm{1.5*\ALs}% medium radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALl{2.25*\ALs}% large radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALh{3*\ALs}% huge radius
 \pgfmathsetmacro\ALt{sqrt(3)*\ALh}% side of triangle
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ALa{0.75*\ALs}% length of arrow
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ALn{0.4*\ALs}% size of node

\tikzset
{midarrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with
 {\arrow[xshift=0.5*\ALa]{Latex[length=\ALa pt,#1]}}},postaction={decorate}},
 full/.style={midarrow},
 open/.style={midarrow={open,fill=white}},
 blob/.style={circle,draw,fill,minimum size=\ALn pt,inner sep=0pt,outer   sep=0pt}
  }

    \newcommand\arrowtype{full}
     % \ARC{start angle}{delta angle clockwise}{radius}
    \newcommand\ARC [3]{\draw[\arrowtype] (X) arc(#1:#1-#2:#3) node{} coordinate   (X);}
   % \LINE{angle}{length}
   \newcommand\LINE[2]{\draw[\arrowtype] (X) -- +(#1:#2) coordinate (X);}

\newcommand\ALdef[1]{\expandafter\def\csname AL:#1\endcsname}
\ALdef{a}{\ARC{ 30}{360}{\ALs pt}}
\ALdef{b}{\ARC{150}{360}{\ALs pt}}
\ALdef{c}{\ARC{270}{360}{\ALs pt}}
\ALdef{d}{\ARC{  0}{360}{\ALm pt}}
\ALdef{e}{\ARC{180}{360}{\ALm pt}}
\ALdef{f}{\ARC{  0}{180}{\ALl pt}}
\ALdef{g}{\ARC{180}{180}{\ALl pt}}
\ALdef{h}{\ARC{ 30}{120}{\ALh pt}}
\ALdef{i}{\ARC{150}{120}{\ALh pt}}
 \ALdef{j}{\ARC{270}{120}{\ALh pt}}
 \ALdef{k}{\ARC{210}{-120}{\ALh pt}}
  \ALdef{0}{\LINE{  0}{\ALt pt}}
  \ALdef{1}{\LINE{ 60}{\ALt pt 
\ALdef{2}{\LINE{120}{\ALt pt}}
\ALdef{3}{\LINE{180}{\ALt pt}}
 \ALdef{4}{\LINE{240}{\ALt pt}}
 \ALdef{5}{\LINE{300}{\ALt pt}}
 \ALdef{F}{\def\arrowtype{full}}
 \ALdef{O}{\def\arrowtype{open}}



 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {image/} }


  \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
  \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
  \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
  \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
   \LARGE
   \renewcommand{\normalsize}
```

I don't know what kind problem there exist. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: First: do not use two documentclasses. Second: Please make your examples MWEs.

Comment: [You have already been told](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365394/add-some-arrows-on-the-picture#comment900315_365394), that you should (always) add a MWE to your question to make it clear. Maybe you'd already find the reason for the problem, if you'd minimize your code.

Comment: I believe the fullpage package is overwriting your headers and footers.