# How to modify given code in order to plot the crossing path and the arrows before p1 and after p3 on my given output

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using some code found on this site here [Add some arrows on the picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365394/add-some-arrows-on-the-picture?rq=1) and trying to get the following plot:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\newcommand\ALloop[1]%
  {\ifx\relax#1%
   \else
     \ifcsname AL:#1\endcsname
       \csname AL:#1\endcsname
     \else
       \GenericError{(AL)}{AL Error: operator #1 undefined}{}{}%
     \fi
   \expandafter\ALloop
   \fi
  }

\newcommand\AL[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,every node/.style={blob}]
       \coordinate(X) at (0,0);
       \ALloop#1\relax
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\def\ALs{12}% small radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALm{1.5*\ALs}% medium radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALl{2.25*\ALs}% large radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALh{3*\ALs}% huge radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALt{sqrt(3.7)*\ALh}% side of triangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALa{0.65*\ALs}% length of arrow
\pgfmathsetmacro\ALn{0.34*\ALs}% size of node

\tikzset
  {midarrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with
     {\arrow[xshift=0.75*\ALa]{Latex[length=\ALa pt,#1]}}},postaction={decorate}},
   full/.style={midarrow},
   open/.style={midarrow={open,fill=white}},
   blob/.style={circle,draw,fill,minimum size=\ALn pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}
  }

\newcommand\arrowtype{full}
% \ARC{start angle}{delta angle clockwise}{radius}
\newcommand\ARC [3]{\draw[\arrowtype] (X) arc(#1:#1-#2:#3) node{} coordinate (X);}


\newcommand\ALdef[1]{\expandafter\def\csname AL:#1\endcsname}

\ALdef{a}{\ARC{270}{180}{\ALl pt}}
\ALdef{b}{\ARC{ 189}{100}{\ALh pt}}
\ALdef{c}{\ARC{90}{180}{\ALh pt}}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{5}

    \newpage

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \AL{bca}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My output is:
[image]

Comment: ... some code found on this site ... -- would you mind posting the URL of the posting from which. you obtained "some code"?

Comment: @Mico I edited my question with the link to the code.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s still unclear what you want. Add more spirals? Stylized or scribbled? The crossing path? Intersections? Please clarify in your question. Thank you

Comment: I want to plot the crossing path and the arrows before p1 and after p3.

Comment: Please. Move. Your. Comment. To, The. Question. For the simple reason, everything needed to know will be neatly available in one place, the question, and not littered accross the page (a myrad of comments). Thank you

Comment: ANALYSIS: If I see it correctly, a `coordinate (X)` is defined inside the `\ARC` macro. It can be used by Tikz in macro ÀL` for some reason. However, it's not clear to me if and how these 3 coordinates created inside your tabular are preserved. // So a SOLUTION might be to look for `tikzmark` examples on this site, set such tikzmarks with `X` and overlay an other tikzpicture, probably below your tabular. // CONCLUSION: All in all it looks like much effort to me with little effect and alternative ways to obtain easier what you want with cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had better luck looking for examples of how to do this, which I found interesting. Within the code you can find the links to the preceding examples.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,intersections}

%this code is from Guilherme Zanotelli  in a "short" explanation in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333824/154390 [start]
\newcommand\bonusspiral{} % just for safety
% \bonusspiral[draw options](placement)(start angle:end angle)(start radius:final radius)[revolutions]
\def\bonusspiral[#1](#2)(#3:#4)(#5:#6)[#7]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\domain}{#4+#7*360}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\growth}{180*(#6-#5)/(pi*(\domain-#3))}
    \draw [#1,
    shift={(#2)},
    domain=#3*pi/180:\domain*pi/180,
    variable=\t,
    name path=plotA,
    %smooth,
    samples=int(\domain/5)] plot ({\t r}: {#5+\growth*\t-\growth*#3*pi/180});
}

%this code is from Frunobulax https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445690/154390
\makeatletter
\pgfset{
    /pgf/decoration/randomness/.initial=2,
    /pgf/decoration/wavelength/.initial=100
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sketch}{init}{
    \state{init}[width=0pt,next state=draw,persistent precomputation={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t0
    }]{}
    \state{draw}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
    auto corner on length=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
    persistent precomputation={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t{mod(\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t+pow(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/randomness},rand),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/wavelength})}
    }]{
        \pgfmathparse{sin(2*\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t*pi/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/wavelength} r)}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
    \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{pencildraw/.style={decorate,decoration={sketch,segment length=1pt,amplitude=2pt}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        Ina/.style={
            draw,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position #1 with {
                        \fill[xscale=-1,xshift=-1pt](0:6pt) -- (90+50:4pt) -- (180:2pt) -- (270-50:4pt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    %Start drawing the thing.
    % First spiral that starst from 15 at radious 1 and ends at 120 at radious 3 in two revolutions.
    \bonusspiral[thick,yscale=0.7,pencildraw,Ina=0.97,postaction={Ina=0}](0,0)(15:120)(1:3)[2]  
    \draw[thick,Ina=0,name path=plotB](0,0.2) to [out=100,in=-100] ++ (0,2.5) node[anchor=0]{S};
    \fill [name intersections={of=plotA and plotB, name=E, total=\t}][black]
    \foreach \s in {1,2,...,\t}{(E-\s) circle (2pt) node[inner sep=0,label={[label distance=-0.2em]45:$\rho_\s$}]{}};       
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

ADDENDUM:

To reverse the enumeration I use an additional counter and change the ordering of the counter. `\foreach \s [count=\ss from 1]in {\t,...,2,1}` Keep in mind that when adapting the spiral it was drawn from the inside out, for that reason the arrows are inverted with `xscale=-1`, and the shift is used so that it has a better finish when adapting to the curves. The code allows you to expand the result even with more nodes, all thanks to the `\bonusspiral` macro

NEW RESULT:
[image]

NEW MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,intersections}

%this code is from Guilherme Zanotelli  in a "short" explanation in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333824/154390 [start]
\newcommand\bonusspiral{} % just for safety
% \bonusspiral[draw options](placement)(start angle:end angle)(start radius:final radius)[revolutions]
\def\bonusspiral[#1](#2)(#3:#4)(#5:#6)[#7]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\domain}{#4+#7*360}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\growth}{180*(#6-#5)/(pi*(\domain-#3))}
    \draw [#1,
    shift={(#2)},
    domain=#3*pi/180:\domain*pi/180,
    variable=\t,
    name path=plotA,
    %smooth,
    samples=int(\domain/5)] plot ({\t r}: {#5+\growth*\t-\growth*#3*pi/180});
}

%this code is from Frunobulax https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445690/154390
\makeatletter
\pgfset{
    /pgf/decoration/randomness/.initial=2,
    /pgf/decoration/wavelength/.initial=100
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sketch}{init}{
    \state{init}[width=0pt,next state=draw,persistent precomputation={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t0
    }]{}
    \state{draw}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
    auto corner on length=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
    persistent precomputation={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t{mod(\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t+pow(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/randomness},rand),\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/wavelength})}
    }]{
        \pgfmathparse{sin(2*\pgf@lib@dec@sketch@t*pi/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/wavelength} r)}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
    \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{pencildraw/.style={decorate,decoration={sketch,segment length=1pt,amplitude=2pt}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        Ina/.style={
            draw,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position #1 with {
                        \fill[xscale=-1,xshift=-1pt](0:6pt) -- (90+50:4pt) -- (180:2pt) -- (270-50:4pt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    %Start drawing the thing.
    % First spiral is used as workspace a spiral that starts from 90 at radious 1 and ends at 90 at radious 6.
    \bonusspiral[thick,yscale=0.7,pencildraw,Ina=0.98,postaction={Ina=0}](0,0)(15:120)(1:5)[4]  
    \draw[thick,Ina=0,name path=plotB](0,0.2) to [out=100,in=-100] ++ (0,4) node[anchor=0]{S};
    \fill [name intersections={of=plotA and plotB, name=E, total=\t}][black]
    \foreach \s [count=\ss from 1]in {\t,...,2,1}{(E-\ss) circle (2pt) node[inner sep=0,label={[label distance=-0.2em]45:$\rho_\s$}]{}};        
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it more clearly:

[image: result]

To include it in other documentclasses, use the `graphicx` package to include the compiled pdf.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},
    dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,
    inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1mm},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .1  with {\arrow{Stealth[]}} ,
        mark=at position .45 with {\arrow{Stealth}} ,
        mark=at position .84 with {\arrow{Stealth}} ,
    },
 ]
    % ~~~ arcs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [postaction={decorate}]
         (0,0) 
            arc [start angle=180,end angle=-90,radius=3cm]
            node[pos=.4,dot] (P1) {} 
            node[pos=1 ,dot] (P3) {}
            arc [start angle=270,end angle= 90,radius=22mm]
            node[pos=.8,dot] (P2) {}
            ;
    
    % ~~~ intersecting line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw   (35:7) to[out=225,in=25] 
            (P1)   to[out=205,in=90] 
            (P2)   to[out=280,in=70] 
            (P3)   to[out=290,in=120] 
            +(-30:2)
            ;

    % ~~~ labeling the points ~~~~~~~~          
    \node[yshift=4mm]       at (P1) {$p_1$};
    \node[shift=(135:4mm)]  at (P2) {$p_2$};
    \node[shift=(235:4mm)]  at (P3) {$p_3$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```