# Drawing (upward facing, potentially unlabelled) binary trees and forests in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees, stacking-symbols

I'm trying to figure out how to draw (forests of) potentially undecorated binary trees in Latex. So far, I've looked at the "forest" package, which I couldn't get to work with what I want. I'm hoping to draw binary trees that look like the following:

[image: Tree with one root and 3 leaves]

I'd also like to be able to draw forests of binary trees:

[image: Forest with 3 trees]

And finally, I'd like to be able to compose a forest of n trees with a tree of n leaves by vertical concatenation:

[image: Composition of forest and tree]

I appreciate that the last option might not exist as a built-in thing into a package, but figure I'd ask just in case.

Thanks!

Edit: Just in case anyone comes across this in the future -- the accepted solution works without error for me after updating my MacTex distribution and then compiling with XeLaTeX.

Comment: You would (preferably) set up the design in your preamble. That way you can call on this design style for your forest diagram.

Comment: See my answer to [Drawing tree-like symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364842/110998).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro `\bintree` that takes a tree as an argument using the syntax of the `forest` package.

[image]

is produced by the code:

```
\[
t=\bintree{[[[[][]][]]]} \hspace{2cm} 
f=\bintree{[[[[]]]]}\qquad\bintree{[[[[][]]]]}\qquad\bintree{[[[][[][]]]]}
\]
```

The macro uses a style defined in a `\forestset`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{bintree/.style={for tree={calign=fixed edge angles, grow'=north, edge=very thick, if n children=0{tier=x}{}},
     delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate, for current and siblings={anchor=north}}{}}}}

\newcommand{\bintree}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{.5}{\tiny\begin{forest}bintree #1 \end{forest}}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
t=\bintree{[[[[][]][]]]} \hspace{2cm} 
f=\bintree{[[[[]]]]}\qquad\bintree{[[[[][]]]]}\qquad\bintree{[[[][[][]]]]}
\]

\end{document}
```

The composition is not automated, but can be accomplished by copying and pasting the trees into the leaves. Here is the code for `t` above:

```
\bintree{[[[[<paste tree here>][<paste tree here>]][<paste tree here>]]]}
```

And with the components of `f` pasted in:

`The composition $f\circ t=\bintree{[[[[[[[[]]]]][[[[[][]]]]]][[[[][[][]]]]]]]}$`

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The code is working great for me to draw trees $t$ and the forest $f$. I'm just having a problem with the composition, I keep getting an error that says "Package PGF Math Error: You asked me to calculate '1/0.0', but I cannot divide any number by zero". I honestly have no idea what is going on there, but it only happens when I try to do the composition. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @MathFrak96: Are you using an old version of PGF? There used to be a bug related to this but if was fixed (I think) a few years ago. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204094/125871) for some discussion.

Comment: Good point. I updated my MacTex distribution and now I don't get the same error. However, I get an error that says "Dimension too large". The tree composition looks all wonky now (stuff is overlapping). Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: For context, the composition now looks like [this](https://ibb.co/8Dbpn64).