# How to capitalise every letter in odd position as in memes?

Tags: fonts

For example, `SoMeThInGlIkEtHiS`

How might one achieve this? I am writing a meme paper this is important. . .

Comment: I like this question. Sometimes Latex needs to cheer up :)

Comment: @Diaa I think you mean LaTeX needs to cheer up :)

Comment: @erik good one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit shorter with the `xstring` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newif\ifupper\uppertrue
\newcommand{\mixedcase}[1]{%
\StrSplit{#1}{1}{\currentchr}{\tailchr}%
\ifupper\MakeUppercase{\currentchr}\upperfalse\else\MakeLowercase{\currentchr}\uppertrue\fi%
\IfStrEq{\tailchr}{}{\uppertrue}{\mixedcase{\tailchr}}%
}
\begin{document}
\mixedcase{something like this}
\end{document}
```

Same output as [Andrews answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491861/).

Explanation: split the string at the first character, make this character upper or lower case depending on a toggle (`\ifupper`), switch the toggle, check if there are characters left in the string (the second part of the split is not empty), if yes call the command recursively, if no then reset the toggle for the next time and stop.

Answer (score 6):

A LaTeX3 version, adapted from egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491669/23765):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\markletters}{m}
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % replace spaces with something different
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \c_space_tl }
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { ##1 }
     { ~ } % don't advance the counter and issue a space
     {
      \int_if_odd:nTF { \l_tmpa_int } { \tex_lowercase:D } { \tex_uppercase:D } { ##1 }
      \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
     }
   }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_blank:n { e } { T,F,TF,p }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\markletters{something like this}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think starting every single word with a capital letter would look nicer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different LaTeX3 implementation using regular expressions. A space character is treated as a letter so that the two lines

```
\CaPiTaLiSe{Something like this}
\CaPiTaLiSe{Somethinglikethis}
```

produce slightly different capitalisations:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_evan_letters_seq
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \evan_make_upper:n {
  \str_uppercase:n {#1}
  \cs_set_eq:NN \evan_capitalise:n \evan_make_lower:n
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \evan_make_lower:n {
  \str_lowercase:n {#1}
  \cs_set_eq:NN \evan_capitalise:n \evan_make_upper:n
}
\NewDocumentCommand\CaPiTaLiSe{m}{
  \regex_split:nnN {} {#1} \l_evan_letters_seq
  \cs_set_eq:NN \evan_capitalise:n \evan_make_upper:n
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_evan_letters_seq {\evan_capitalise:n {##1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

  \CaPiTaLiSe{Something like this}

  \CaPiTaLiSe{Somethinglikethis}

\end{document}
```

Rather than incrementing a counter I have a dummy macro `\evan_capitalise:n` that swaps between choosing upper and lower case.

Comment: Rather than `\let`, LaTeX3 offers `\cs_set_eq:NN`. Instead of applying `_nopar` at the `\cs_new...` level (programming layer, affects all arguments), you can use arg specifiers like `+o`, `+m`, etc. in `\NewDocumentCommand` (`+` makes the corresponding arguments *accept* `\par` tokens: the opposite of `no_par`). Also, you may want to take a look at the [LaTeX3 style guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) for spacing and brace placement. By the way, this document talks about  the `no_par` variants in section 4. My (IMHO) two cents. :-)

Comment: @frougon Thanks!
 I thought that there should be a latex3 variant of `\let` but could not find it. Coming from a python background I'm not so fond of the latex spacing recommendations:) In this instance I don't want `\par` tokens!

Comment: You're welcome. I can understand you for the `par` tokens, but consider that arguments of macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` don't accept `\par` *unless* you use the `+` prefix. So, your `\CaPiTaLiSe` is already safe, even without using any `no_par`. Concerning `\evan_make_upper:n` and `\evan_make_lower:n`, I thought they would let `\par` tokens unmodified if the `no_par` were to be removed, but it appears not to be the case, so okay.  :-) If you allow me, I can post a small test I did on pastebin.com, based on your code... (can't put it here with formatting, unfortunately).

Comment: @frougon On the basis of other posts on TeX.Sx I thought that using `\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn` for these "hidden" macros is "better" stylistically, but I have no idea really:) Happy for you to add your code from pastebin. In fact, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @frougon Updated to use `\cs_set_eq:NN`. Thanks!

Comment: [Here you are](https://pastebin.com/Zfp5uK6U). It's mostly yours with the stylistic fixes I mentioned and slight changes to see what `\evan_make_upper:n` and `\evan_make_lower:n` would do without the `no_par` when provided with an argument containing possibly several paragraphs. I'm a bit disappointed by the handling of `\par`. :-/ If you uncomment the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, this handling changes but is not what I expected either...

Comment: @/joseph-wright You know far more about this than I but I do not understand you edit because according to the manual, `\str_uppercase:n` doesn't exist and `\str_upper_case:n` was correct? Similarly, with `\str_lower_case:n`.

Comment: I fear @JosephWright won't see your notification? Anyway, look at [LaTeX3 commit d5296c790e](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/d5296c790ec24a25b6082071f20edb8c74f0d028). The changes to `l3kernel/l3deprecation.dtx` indicate that `\str_upper_case:n` and `\str_lower_case:n` are deprecated and will trigger an error when the `expl3` date is more recent than 2021-01-01.

Comment: @Andrew We have just updated `expl3` with some renames: the new code was available in TeX Live from today, so I'm looking to update answers to reflect this. One of the team will post a 'what happened to the old names' question/answer shortly.